# Why does DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract give me a massive number sometimes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, timer

Why does the DateTime.Subtract return really odd values sometimes?

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Request> _waitingList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Request>();

// send requests in thread #1 and set their SentAt time
_waitingList.TryAdd(macAddress, request);
request.SentAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

// then in a timer tick event in different thread every 5 seconds
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
   foreach (var waiting in _waitingList) { // ConcurrentDictionary<string, Request>
      var request = waiting.Value;
      var msSinceSent = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(request.SentAt).TotalMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"sent *{request.Type}* {msSinceSent} ms ago");
   }
}
```

> ```
> sent *PackageUpdate* 336.2019 ms ago
> sent *PackageUpdate* 698.1145 ms ago
> sent *PackageUpdate* 1059.864 ms ago
> sent *PackageUpdate* 63693095680615.5 ms ago
> ```

The last value is massive, I get these every so often and cannot understand how that is even possible.

Comment: What data type is `request.SentAt`?

Comment: @DavidG DateTime

Comment: And are you absolutely sure you are using `.Milliseconds` rather than `.TotalMilliseconds`?

Comment: @DavidG yes sorry I am using .TotalMilliseconds, I had just changed it the last minute. I have updated my question with all the details but not too much.

Answer (score 3):

If `request.SentAt` is a set to `DateTime.MinValue` you will get that value. I assume it was null or zero in your data store and that is converting to `DateTime.MinValue` somewhere.

For example, this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Will output this value:

> 63693097183442.7